# Macbook Pro Display Ghosting

Tags: display, macbook

I have MacBook Pro Early 2015. My display is acting abnormal. Extreme ghosting appears even on the login screen after Macbook Pro restart - with images from previous session… Furthermore white background (e.g. on MS Word or Excel) became grey and they are many other color changes.I tried SMC and PVRAM reset but it did not help.
Any solution?

[image: Problem Photo]

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm this is unusual. It might be something to do with the retina. Oh wait it's really simple: Go to

> System Preferences -> Displays -> (Built-in Retina Display) Color tab
> -> Calibrate...

In Calibration, drag the white point slider to the far right (most blue light). This causes the screen to become extremely blue, so to cancel this out:

Select Night shift, adjust warmth to preferred level (far right for best results), and set up the night shift schedule to always be on. this is what worked for me. it will save you $2000 for around 1-2 years. This is a sign of the screen life coming to an end.

Let me know if this helped -NMD